# Storing data with multiple parts to it per submission

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I will try and be as clear as I can...

I have a requirement to store data records that contain multiple items per incident. Let’s just say in one incident I have a customer that has stolen 9 pieces of food... 1 banana, 3 blue skittles, 2 mars bars and 4 orange slices.

I have a table that contains the incident core details (date, time, incident details, etc) and is identified against the UID of the person involved, with the persons personal details stored in another table with their UID. The requirement is to be able to run a report to see how many of each object were stolen.

How is the best way for me to store these records in relation to data performance, ect as this obviously has the potential to get huge table lines out of every multiple object incident.

Do I save them as multiple records with reference to the incidents parent record ID, or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You can write pivot table like table_stolen_products 
with fields product_id and person_id , so you can easily access details of both product and person by joining these table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point, I would do something like this:
[image]

The Incident_has_FoodItems allows you to link an arbitrary number of FoodItems to your Incident table.  It is then easy to count how many times each FoodItem appears in your Incident_has_FoodItems table.

When you define a database data structure, separate each item as a table and link these together.  They allow for easier query, better performance, easier to create indexes, ...

You can read up on normal forms if you want to dig further.

Comment: Very nice, @Nic.  What tool did you do that in?

Comment: fabForce DB Designer 4.  It is an old software for MySQL, but it works great.  Only thing to do with auto-generated SQL is to replace TYPE= by ENGINE=.  It is enough for quick and dirty DB setups, and free!

Comment: @Nic thanks heaps for that suggestion. Makes a lot more sense to break it down the way you’ve suggested. Then I am only requesting the individual incidents on initial search, but can then drill down further to see each group of related items. :-) Very much appreciated!